# How to get a string constructed from a filename to use a language define?

Tags: php, arrays, text

**I have been searching high and low for the answer to this one:**

```
$file_type_array = array();
$file_type_array[] = array('id' => $file, 'text' => PULL_DOWN_DEFAULT);
  while ($file = readdir($resc)) {
  $ext = strrchr($file, ".");
  if ($ext == ".php") {
    $filename = str_replace(' ', "_", $file);
    $filename = str_replace('-', "_", $filename);
    $filename = str_replace($ext, "", $filename);

    $string_define_filename = 'TEXT_' . strtoupper($filename);

    $file_type_array[] = array('id' => $file, 'text' => $string_define_filename);
  }
}
```

**So what I am trying to achieve is:**

1. Get filenames from directory
2. Remove any spaces or - from the names
3. Uppercase them and prefix 'TEXT_'

**and then my problem:**

4) Output the result of define('TEXT_{filename}, 'This is the translated name of the filename'); rather than the uppercase text.

**Can anyone help?**

Comment: What's the purpose of doing the `define()` call? "dynamic" constants don't make any sense.

Comment: The define is set in another language file: So we have English, German, Spanish, French, etc.  When the above code executes I get TEXT_LIKE_THIS_IN_THE_DROP_DOWN when in fact i want it to look up the definition of the UPPERCASE in the external language php files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`constant`](http://php.net/constant) function.

Comment: Thanks I will have a look at this.

Answer (score 1):

*Your code can be rewrited as follow:*

```
$file_type_array[] = array('id' => $file, 'text' => PULL_DOWN_DEFAULT);
 while ($file = readdir($resc)) {
  $f = pathinfo($file);
  if ($f['extension'] == "php") {
    $filename = preg_replace('/[^\w\d]+/i','_',$f['filename']);
    $string_define_filename = 'TEXT_' . strtoupper($filename);
    define($string_define_filename,$file); //optional
    $file_type_array[] = array('id' => $filename, 'text' => constant($string_define_filename));
  }  
}
foreach( $file_type_array as $def ) {
       echo $def['text'] . "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **constant** as suggested this worked for me:

```
$file_type_array = array();
$file_type_array[] = array('id' => $file, 'text' => PULL_DOWN_DEFAULT);
while ($file = readdir($resc)) {
  $ext = strrchr($file, ".");
  if ($ext == ".php") {
    $filename = str_replace(' ', "_", $file);
    $filename = str_replace('-', "_", $filename);
    $filename = str_replace($ext, "", $filename);

  if (constant('TEXT_' . strtoupper($filename)) != null) {
    $filename_string = constant('TEXT_' . strtoupper($filename));
  } else {
    $filename_string = 'Missing language define for TEXT_' . strtoupper($filename);
}

  $file_type_array[] = array('id' => $file, 'text' => $filename_string);
  } 
}
```

(Added a conditional check in case filename not defined in the language file)

**Thank you to everyone who posted for their help!**